# How can I download email attachments only when requested?

Tags: email, attachments

The default email application seems to be downloading email attachments when I try to read an email.

I don't want to download attachment by default, it should on request. I should be able to read the mail body text without needing to download the attachment.

I am using my own POP3 server and not GMail.

Is there any way to enable this or another application which I can use for this?

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace Model GT-S5830.

Answer (score 11):

[K-9 Mail](https://market.android.com/search?q=K-9%20Mail) does load attachments only on request. *But* your problem is not only the Client, it's more the protocol used for retrieving E-Mail: **[POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3) does not support the partial download of an E-Mail without their attachment(s)**, whereas [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) does. Besides of that IMAP has some nice extensions when it comes to mobile usage: [Lemonade Profiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemonade_Profile)

Comment: Is the link to 'Lemonade Profiles' still up to date? Looks like an ordinary blog to me and I didnt find anythin IMAP related. The oldest entry is June 2012. Did someone take over the domain?

Comment: @PetPaulsen Hmm, maybe. I changed the link to Wikipedia for now

Answer (score 2):

Both the POP3 and your email client are issues.

As prior poster pointed out, POP3 doesn't support partial downloading.  However, many email clients do support limiting message download size.  By setting up the right limit, you can just download message but not the attachment. When you click on attachment, you'll be asked whether you want to download the attachment.  This method does work.

If you're current mail client does not support this, consider changing clients.  I too use k-9 and feel it is pretty good, plus its free (open source).  k-9 does support limiting download size on POP3 accounts.

If you're email provider supports IMAP, you ought to switch.  IMAP is way way better.